# Empty space remove from a python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

From a text file I have generated this python list.

`[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'EXAMPLE', 'EXAMPLE_1', 'EXAMPLE_2', 'EXAMPLE_3']`

But I want to remove this empty spaces and ' ', from my list. I suggestions from your side.

Expected output
`['EXAMPLE', 'EXAMPLE_1', 'EXAMPLE_2', 'EXAMPLE_3']`

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Consider using a [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) to iterate over your existing list and create the list you want.

Comment: `clean_list = [i for i in dirty_list if i.strip()]` will do it but I would absolutely prefer to fix the code that builds the list and avoid this all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension like this to get your result:

```
l = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'EXAMPLE', 'EXAMPLE_1', 'EXAMPLE_2', 'EXAMPLE_3']
l_m = [x.strip() for x in l] #temp list
[x for x in l_m if len(x)]
```

Output:

```
['EXAMPLE', 'EXAMPLE_1', 'EXAMPLE_2', 'EXAMPLE_3']
```

Comment: The temp list is unnecessary here - you can accomplish this in a single comprehension